# XPath query for XML attribute with colon of the node

Tags: python, xpath

All
I used the XPath lib in Python language. but I can't get some attribute with colon in my xml file.

The xml file content:

```
  xmlns:rtr="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content"
    <packageItem conformance="power" guid="2013-07-17 15:53:21" standard="NewsML-G2" standardversion="2.14" version="1" xml:lang="en">
    <itemClass qcode="icls:composite" rtr:msgType="S"/>
```

These are two method I have written.

```
def getxmlVal(self, expr):
    data = xpath.findvalue(expr, self.doc)
    return data
def getValnamespaces(self, expr, namespace):
    context = xpath.XPathContext(default_namespace=namespace)
    return context.findvalue(expr, self.doc);
```

I also tried:
for the method **getxmlVal**

1. expr=
       "//packageItem/itemMeta/itemClass/*[local-name()='rtr:msgType' and
       namespace-uri()='http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content']";
2. `expr= "//itemMeta/itemClass/*[name()='rtr:msgType']";`

for the method **getValnamespaces**

```
expr= "//itemMeta/itemClass/*[name()='rtr:msgType']"; 
namespace = "http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content";
```

but I can get `None`

What's wrong with my method?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is poorly formed, and its really difficult to see what you've tried. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have changed it. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@` to match an attribute, and you shouldn't specify the namespace while trying to match `local-name()`:

```
expr= "//packageItem/itemMeta/itemClass/@*[local-name()='msgType' and namespace-uri()='http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content']";
```